# Android upgrading older version. New version has a new permission in manifest, but when I upgrade, the app crashes and it says I need that permission

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a master branch and a new_feature branch.
I have upgraded DB version in new_feature branch and in order to test what will happen to users that have installed master version from Google Play,
in Eclipse I run a version with the master branch and install it on my device.
Then I switch branch, refresh, clean and I run the new_feature version on top of the other one.

The new_feature branch has a

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

permission in order to carry on a certain task.

When the new version is installed (which supposedly has this permission in the manifest) the app crashes and it says I need that permission for that task.

Its like its using the old manifest for the new code?
Is this a bug in Eclipse or Android?

**EDIT:**

Next time I tried, I ran the MASTER version on my device, then deleted the project from eclipse workspace, switched branch, reimported project in eclipse workspace, and ran the new version, the problem didnt occur

Comment: No idea about your exact question since I've never seen it before but as a matter of interest, do you have different version codes between the two branches? (with your new_feature having a higher version code). If not, can you try changing the versions and see if that forces a manifest update?

Comment: Manifest versions are completely different

Comment: What is the compile version of new apk? android.permission.GET_TASKS is not going to enforce from Lolipop.

Comment: android:minSdkVersion="14"
android:targetSdkVersion="19"

Comment: running on a JellyBean device when this happens

Comment: I have updated my question with how I think I fixed the issue. I hope it was an Eclipse bug

Comment: @J.K. You should post normal answer then, not edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time I tried, I ran the MASTER version on my device, then deleted the project from eclipse workspace, switched branch, reimported project in eclipse workspace, and ran the new version, the problem didnt occur

I hope it was a bug in Eclipse and will not happen to users who will update from Google Play when I release the NEW_FEATURE branch version